# Rose2003 Forward Engineering Error in Win7(x86)

Tags: sql-server, rational-rose

My System Info:
Win7(x86)
Rational Rose 2003
MS SQLServer 2008 R2

Problem:
when I use rose "Foward Engineering Wizard" ,there's a problem:
An unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will be shut down immediately.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no %CommonProgramFiles%\System\ado\msado15 in shared library path.

Attempt to solve:
I have tried to edit my System Path ,and it doesn't work,too.
In Windows Xp ,there's no problem in "Foward Engineering".

Question:
How can I use "Foward Engineering Wizard" in Win7(x86),and how to solve it?
Thanks a lot !